# Conditionally excluding field not working in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, projection

I would like to get a user from the database. My function takes in a `requesterId` which is the ID of the user requesting this data, and a `targetId` which is the user to retrieve.

If the requester is in the target's `friends` array (strings), the `phone` field should be included in the projection. If not, it is excluded.

I have come up with the following query after reading the example [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#remove-example). However, the `phone` field is always returned no matter what. What am I doing wrong?

```
  getUser: function getUser(requesterId, targetId) {
    return db.collection('users').aggregate([
      {$match: {userId: targetId}},
      {
        $project:
          {
            firstName: 1,
            phone: {
              $cond: {
                if: {friends: requesterId},
                then: "$phone",
                else: "$$REMOVE"
              }
            }
          }
      },
      {$limit: 1}
    ]).toArray();
  }
```

**Schema** (created in Compass so no code):
`userId` - String
`firstName` - String
`friends` - Array(String)
`phone` - String

**Indices**:
*None on this collection*

**Example**:

```
/* Bob's MongoDB data */ {userId: "BobID", firstName: "Bob", friends: ["AmyID"], phone: "1234567890"}
getUser(requesterId = 'AmyID', targetId = 'BobID');
/* Result */ {firstName: "Bob", phone: "1234567890"}

/* Amy's MongoDB data */ {userId: "AmyID", firstName: "Amy", friends: ["CassieID"], phone: "9876543210"}
getUser(requesterId = 'BobID', targetId = 'AmyID');
/* Result */ {firstName: "Amy", phone: "987654321"}
```

Bob's request for Amy's user should not return her phone number because he is not in her `friends` array.

Comment: use `$filter` aggregation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection

Comment: Can you post the schemas?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I'm unclear as to how`$filter` will help here. I'm not trying to get any results from the `friends` array, I would just like to check that the parameter is in that array so I can include or exclude an entirely separate field.

Comment: ok could you post sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if:` value must be a boolean expression, not a query object. To check whether a specified value is in an array, you can use the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/#exp._S_in) expression:

```
db.collection('users').aggregate([
  {$match: {userId: targetId}},
  {
    $project:
      {
        firstName: 1,
        phone: {
          $cond: {
            if: {$in: [requesterId, '$friends']},
            then: "$phone",
            else: "$$REMOVE"
          }
        }
      }
  },
  {$limit: 1}
])
```